# Are there any real-valued functions, besides logarithms, for which $f(x*y) = f(x) + f(y)$?

Tags: functional-equations

Is there any real-valued function, $f$, which is not a logarithm, such that $∀ x,y$ in $ℝ$ , $f(x*y) = f(x) + f(y)$?

So far, all I can think of is $z$ where $z(x) = 0$  $∀ x$ in $ℝ$

**EDIT:**

Functions having a domain of $ℝ^+$ or a domain of $ℝ$/{0} are acceptable as well.

What are examples of functions, $f$, from $ℝ$/{0} to $ℝ$ which are not logarithms, such that
$∀ x,y$ in $ℝ$, $f(x*y) = f(x) + f(y)$?

Comment: If you take a closer look, the constant zero function is also the *only* function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$, period. Logarithms do not satisfy that property.

Comment: Probably you want functions $\mathbb R_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Comment: See [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423494) under the `related equations` section.

Answer (score 7):

$f(0\times 0)=f(0)+f(0)$ so $f(0)=0$. Put $x=0$ to get $f(0)=f(0)+f(y)$. Hence $f \equiv 0$. Note that this is the answer when the domain is the whole real line.

Comment: I already gave that example in the original posting. I wrote, "So far, all I can think of is $z$ where$z(x)=0$ $∀x$ in $R$"

Comment: I am not giving an example. I am proving that there is no other solution if the equation is to hold for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are, at least if you assume the axiom of choice. Then there are functions $g\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which are not linear but which satisfy Cauchy's functional equation:

> $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$.

Now, define

> $f\colon(0,+\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$
>   by
>   $f(x)=g\bigl(\log(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: OP clearly says 'for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$', so the domain is not $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But the OP also clearly mentions logarithms, so he probably may have mistaken saying "for all $\in \mathbb R$".

Comment: Quite possible. Let us see how he reacts.